# The statement has been terminated SQL management studio

Tags: ssms

I have made a query in SQL management studio which is as follows :-

```
ALTER TABLE [TransactionNote] 
ALTER COLUMN NoteLine [varchar] 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
```

Why do I see

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 4
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

in the output window.?

Comment: Because otherwise the string or binary data would have been truncated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the new length for your `NoteLine` field. If no length is specified for a `varchar`, it will default to a length of 1. Any current values in that field that are longer than 1 character would be truncated, hence the error message.

Determine how long the longest value is in that field, and then `ALTER` the column accordingly.

```
select max(len(NoteLine) from TransactionNote;
```

Make note of the result.

```
ALTER TABLE [TransactionNote] 
ALTER COLUMN NoteLine [varchar(VALUE_FROM_BEFORE)] 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Thanks Alroc. that did help.